Is there a non-Piecewise function with a derivative non continuous
I was looking for a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with a non-continuous derivative, and I found it easily an example using piecewise functions, like $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})&x\neq 0\\0\quad &x=0\end{cases}$.
However I haven't found any examples without the use of Piecewise functions, so my questions are:
1. is it possible to find a non-Piecewise function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that it's derivative (defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$) it's not continuous
2. is it possible to find one (always non-Piecewise, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ ) using only elementary functions
To clarify:

By Piecewise I mean this
By Elementary function I am referring to these, but I am only interested in those defined in $\mathbb{R}$ and derivable in $\mathbb{R}$


I don't know if the examples-counterexamples tag is correct

If you're looking for a combination of elementary functions and operations, the answer is "No" for a very simple reason: all the elementary functions are continuously differentiable (where they are defined) and there are theorems that say the elementary operations of continuously differentiable functions are again continuously differentiable (when defined).

There is no such thing as a piecewise function . Any function can be cosidered as  a piecewise function .

@jjagmath okay thanks, so it's "No" to both questions?

I guess that strictly speaking, it depends on what exactly you accept as elementary functions and operations. I'm thinking in elementary functions as: polynomials, trigonometric functions, exponential and logarithmic, and elementary operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, composition.

yes, I would just add the hyperbolic functions to your list.
But for the first question you can use any non-Piecewise function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

If you include inverses of elementary functions, you can get around my argument and construct "piecewise functions" without piecewise definitions. For example, $|x| =\sqrt{x^2}$.

I did include the hyperbolic functions: those are combinations of the exponential and some elementary operations.

Okay, I'll refer to these as elementary function:
sums, products, roots and compositions of finitely many polynomial, rational, trigonometric, hyperbolic, and exponential functions, and their inverses.
But I am only interested in those defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and derivable in \mathbb{R}

How about $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ which is continuous but not smooth at $x=0$?

okay, but derivative is not defined in $x=0$
